# CocoaPods was not able to update the `master-1` repo

Tags: ios, iphone

I user cocoapods update libs in china, the network of my county is limited.
so...

Podfile  add one line : "pod 'SQLCipher' "
I run :

```
pod install --no-repo-update
```

failed!

remove 'pod SQLCipher'

run:

```
pod install --no-repo-update .
```

error:

```
[!] CocoaPods was not able to update the `master-1` repo. If this is an unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose`
```

run:

```
pod repo update --verbose
```

loading... forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found problem. I import 'SQLCipher' by add 'SQLCipher.h' 'SQLCipher.c' files.

then Error.

solved by remove the two files.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like your specs repo was edited at some point, and now git can't update it.

I'd recommend deleting and re-creating your Specs repo;

**Run below command:**

`pod repo remove master`

and then setup new by running

`pod setup`

Comment: "running" is not a part of this command. The right command is `pod setup`. Answer edited with correct one.